# How I get the index of especific row to delete it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this array:

```
{"actividades":[
    {"id_miembro":"V-005","id_dpto":"D-01","id_actividad":"AC-04","id_seccion":"S-03"},
    {"id_miembro":"V-006","id_dpto":"D-01","id_actividad":"AC-01","id_seccion":"S-02"},
    {"id_miembro":"V-007","id_dpto":"D-01","id_actividad":"AC-02","id_seccion":"S-01"},
    {"id_miembro":"V-008","id_dpto":"D-01","id_actividad":"AC-03","id_seccion":"S-01"}
]}
```

How can i get the index of the array when `"id_miembro" = "V-007"` to delete this data from array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply using JavaScript's [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

Assuming:

```
myObj = {"actividades":[
    {"id_miembro":"V-005","id_dpto":"D-01","id_actividad":"AC-04","id_seccion":"S-03"},
    {"id_miembro":"V-006","id_dpto":"D-01","id_actividad":"AC-01","id_seccion":"S-02"},
    {"id_miembro":"V-007","id_dpto":"D-01","id_actividad":"AC-02","id_seccion":"S-01"},
    {"id_miembro":"V-008","id_dpto":"D-01","id_actividad":"AC-03","id_seccion":"S-01"}
]}
```

Then:

```
myObj.actividades = myObj.actividades.filter(function(e){
    return e.id_miembro !== "V-007";
});
```

(`.filter` returns the filtered array. I'm assigning it to the old object, as a replacement, but you can use it in any variable you want, of course)

However, `.filter()`'s IE support is IE 9+. You might want to use the plyfill provided in the MDN link if you want to support older browsers.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with `$.grep()`,

```
var newArray = $.grep(xObj.actividades,function(val,i){
  return val.id_miembro !== "V-007";
});
```

**Note:** i just assume that you are having that JSON in a variable called `xObj`

API: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/

Comment: Think you have the `i, val` mixed up - index is the second param in `grep` - "Type: Function( Object elementOfArray, Integer indexInArray ) "

Comment: @tymeJV Yeah, that's right.. edited accordingly. And i wonder is there any easy way to memorize that, because i always get confused while using `.each()` and others.. :)

Comment: I confuse them all the time...one day it will click...maybe :\

Comment: i realice the test with .grep, and it delete the search row, but the json array return this:     {[
    {"id_miembro":"V-005","id_dpto":"D-01","id_actividad":"AC-04","id_seccion":"S-03"},
    {"id_miembro":"V-006","id_dpto":"D-01","id_actividad":"AC-01","id_seccion":"S-02"},
    {"id_miembro":"V-008","id_dpto":"D-01","id_actividad":"AC-03","id_seccion":"S-01"}
]} it's seems that the index "actividades" is deleted

Comment: How can i do that?, i'm new in this

Comment: as you can see the json array starts {[{"id_miembro.... but the right value should be {"actividades":[{"id_miembro... see?

Answer (score 0):

Other answer are great for removing an element by in an array, but in case you want the index, here a little function for you :

```
function getIndex(arr, key, val, single){
    var rArr = $.map(arr, function(obj, i){
        if(obj[key] === val) return i;
    });

    return single ?
        (rArr.length ? rArr[0] : -1):
        rArr; 
}
```

You can the call it like that :

var myIndex = getIndex(obj.actividades, 'id_miembro', 'V-007', true);

Where parameters goes like this :

1. The object you are searching in;
2. The key you are looking at;
3. The value that match;
4. Return a single index [integer] or all matches [array].

Here's a live example : http://jsfiddle.net/wLDR2/

Answer (score -1):

It's easy with a library like [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/docs#findIndex):

```
var index = _.findIndex(array.actividades, { 'id_miembro': 'V-007' });
```

See it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vh7f/).

Comment: There's really no need to import a library for a function native JS supports. Also, this isn't really the result the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Cerbrus Code is more clear with Lo-Dash. Also, it provides a lot of functionality that OP can use in other parts of the code.